# Mimir github actions metrics collection

Tags: github, github-actions, grafana, monitoring, metrics

What is currently the best way to collect metrics from GitHub about actions, such as duration, workflow status, error rate, etc? I found a few actions in marketplace, but they seem to be outdated. We are using LGTM stack so Mimir with Grafan for metrics collection and dashboards

I've tried to connect it through a few GH actions, but it seems very limited. The only viable solution seems to be using the workflow webhook, but it looks like overkill in a broader perspective